# How to add multiple CCSprites inside CCArray

Tags: xcode, arrays, cocos2d-iphone

If I for example had fruits in my game and would like to add all fruit CCSprites to the CCArray how would I do that?

say I have the following code:

```
CCSprite *Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple2.png"];
CCSprite *Banana = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Banana2.png"];
```

and this is my CCArray:

```
CCArray *FruitsArray = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Banana.png", @"Apple.png", nil];// Why is this not working? 
self.FruitsArray = [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

I want the FruitsArray to have a capacity of 10, so it should hold 10 apples and bananas.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not working because its not valid syntax for calling spriteWithFile function:

```
 [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Banana.png", @"Apple.png", nil];
```

Syntax:

```
+(id) spriteWithFile:(NSString*)filename;
// Returns Object of CCSprite class
```

« Why can't you derive CCSprite class and override spriteWithFile on your need basis?

```
 OR
```

« Why can't you add each object like this?

```
   CCArray *fruitsArray = [CCArray array];
   CCSprite *Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple2.png"];
   CCSprite *Banana = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Banana2.png"]; 

   [fruitsArray addObject: Apple];       
   [fruitsArray addObject: Banana];
```

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean by this. Can you explain a bit more please. I am new to programming.